# PHP Syntax of an href with row variable

Tags: php, syntax, href

I am a newbie trying to write some php code and I am having some issues with the else statement.I believe it to be the href part that is throwing the error because it seems to work well until I add the **href**. I don't understand what is missing but at this point I have looked at the code so much.It could be obvious and I wouldn't see it. I would like to have the Link_ID row concatenate with the http link

```
if(empty($row['Link_ID'])){
   echo "<td>" . $row['Song'] . '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp' . "<img src=GoButton-grey.gif></td>";
}else{ 
   echo "<td>" . $row['Song'] . '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp' . <a href="www.imdb.com/' . $row['Link_ID'] .'"> "<img src=GoButton.gif></a></td>";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You're missing the http protocol from your url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code should be :

```
if(empty($row['Link_ID'])){

echo "<td>" . $row['Song'] . '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp' . "<img src=GoButton-grey.gif></td>";

}else{ 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Song'] . "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <a href='http://www.imdb.com/".$row['Link_ID']."'> <img src=GoButton.gif></a></td>";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be concatenating the link_ID to the href

Answer (score 1):

There is missing HTTP protocol (link target in ELSE) and quote marks mismatch.

```
if (empty($row['Link_ID'])) {
    echo '<td>' . $row['Song'] . '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<img src="GoButton-grey.gif"></td>';
} else { 
    echo '<td>' . $row['Song'] . '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<a href="http://www.imdb.com/' . $row['Link_ID'] . '"><img src="GoButton.gif"></a></td>';
    //                                                      ^ http protocol
}
```